# Hive Dynamic Partition with Multiple Files in Each Partition

Tags: hadoop, hive

This is how am dynamically partitioning the data, but only a single file is getting created per partition but I want each file to be of 256MB in size.

And since my data is heavily skewed, some files associated with Partitions are 2-3 GB in size rightnow... I tried so many settings, but none of them worked.

Am using MR mode.

Can someone please let me know what could be done here to create multiple files per partitions where each file should be of 256MB in size ?

```
SET hive.execution.engine=mr;
SET hive.exec.scratchdir=/tmp/hive/ ;
SET hive.exec.stagingdir=/tmp/hive/;

set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=250000000;
set mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent=0.15;

insert overwrite table madlytics.events_eors20_hive_dynamic_part partition(h='01',event_type)
select
*, h, event_type
from
madlytics.events_eors_2017_09_20 where h = '01' distribute by event_id sort by event_type;
```

Comment: is there a reason why you want to make smaller files?

Comment: If the files are splittable, then there's no benefit to making them smaller

Comment: yeah since the ouput format is ORC they are splittable at stripe level , but as per the ORC best practice I want to keep it at 256MB and also since am writing to S3 and S3 has an limit of 5GB per object, my worry is job might fail when it reaches that limit

Comment: try clustering your table (CLUSTERED BY .. into x buckets) and enable hive.enforce.bucketing on insert. this will give you x files per partition.